# Nested for loops to fill a list of lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing, nested

I'm trying to fill a list of lists as below:

```
Qlist = [[] for i in range(len(bestgr))]  


for par in bestgr:

    for day in range(71,72):

        for n in range(len(bestgr)):

            option_data, index_prices, initial_date = getsamedatedopt(fullData, day, 1)

            gr = groupbyttm(option_data)

            normk, norm_opt, tau, kind, k = intdata(gr, index_prices)

            I = intrect(gr, norm_opt, normk, index_prices, kind, par, tau, k)

            q = int2D(I, gr, tau)

            Qlist[n].append(q)
```

In this code, "bestgr" is a list of parameter set expressed as dictionaries. What I want to do is compute the q with the code above for each parameter set and for each day. The code should fill the lists inside Qlist with a number of values equal to the number of days considered. In other words I need each list in Qlist to be associated to one parameter set and containing all the q computed for that particular set ineach day considered. In the example above I have bestpar made of 2 elements and just one day, so I should obtain a list of 2 lists made of just one element (the first one contains the q computed for the first set in the selected day and the second one contains the q computed for the  second set in the selected day). Unfortunately , what I get is `[[2.6501, 2.6556], [2.6501, 2.6556]]`, instead of `[[2.6501], [2.6556]]`. How can I obtain such output?

**EDIT**

The functions used in the code above concern the computation of a double integral over the moneyness and the maturity for given samedated options. "Bestgr" contains the parameter sets for the model used to price my options, while day is the number passed as argument to `getsamedatedopt` function. This function extracts option data of the corresponding day (and consequently all the elemente needed to compute the final value q of the integral). I want to fill the empty the list of lists looping over the parameter sets and the days of dataset.

I should expect that a list inside Qlist contains the double integral values q for each day considered in the dataset at a given parameter set. Therefore each nested list refers to a single parameter set and contain a number of values equal to the number of day of dataset considered. What I get with the code above is a repetition of values, because if I have 2 parameter sets and a single day of dataset, I would expect two nested lists inside Qlist, each containing 1 single value.
To be more specific I should obtain:

Qlist = [ [day1set1] [day1set2]]

not Qlist = [ [day1set1, day1set2] [day1set1, day1set2] ]

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Please explain more clearly what you want, what you get, what you would expect to get and the exact form of your data.

Comment: @mrCarnivore I edited the question. It is not easy to explain because there's a lot of work behind and maybe I was taking something for granted. I hope now it is more understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement `Qlist[n].append(q)` adds a value to the n-th sublist. Let's see how often it is executed

```
par day n    -> 
0   71  0    Qlist[0].append(q)
0   71  1    Qlist[1].append(q)
1   71  0    Qlist[0].append(q)
1   71  1    Qlist[1].append(q)
```

I think this table makes obvious why you end up with 2 values per sublist.

Here's a much less complex version of your code which hopefully does what you want:

```
qslist = []  
for par in bestgr:
    qlist = []
    for day in range(71,72):
        option_data, index_prices, initial_date = getsamedatedopt(fullData, day, 1)
        # blah blah blah domain-specific stuff
        q = int2D(I, gr, tau)
        qlist.append(q)
   qslist.append(qlist)
```

Always remember: it's easy to create complex, incomprehensible code which doesn't work. What we should strive for is the opposite: working code, as simple and readable as possible.

Comment: That's exactly the solution I was searching for. I didn't think about writing the for loops like that. Thank you